# Akka-Http: Connect timeout expired

Tags: rest, http, akka-http

I am trying to generate a PUT request using akka http, with my rest service end point which works as expected when done using curl, but shows time out error when I am generating it by creating Http connection.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.CirceSupport
import io.circe.Json
import org.joda.time.DateTime

case class JobDetails (jobName: String, appId: Option[String]=None, status: Option[String]=None,runningSince:Option[Long]=None)

trait UpdateJobStatus extends CirceSupport with Config {


  def UpdateJobDetails(jobDetails :JobDetails) {


    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("update")
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val DetailsList = List(
      ("jobName",Json.fromString(jobDetails.jobName)),
      ("appId",Json.fromString(jobDetails.appId.get)),
      ("status",Json.fromString(jobDetails.status.get)),
      ("runningSince",Json.fromLong(DateTime.now.getMillis)))

    val jobDetailJson:Json = Json.fromFields(DetailsList)


    val endpoint =Uri.from(scheme = "http",host = httpHost,port = 9000,path = "/updateJobDetails/TestJob")

    val updateRequest = HttpRequest(
      HttpMethods.PUT,
      uri = endpoint,
      entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, jobDetailJson.toString()))

    Http().singleRequest(updateRequest)


  }
}

object Test extends App with UpdateJobStatus{

  val test = JobDetails("TestJob",Some("1234"),Some("Killed"),Some(21))
 UpdateJobDetails(test)

}
```

error :

```
DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:02.934] [main] [EventStream(akka://UpdateService)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:02.935] [main] [EventStream(akka://UpdateService)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:03.122] [main] [AkkaSSLConfig(akka://UpdateService)] Initializing AkkaSSLConfig extension...
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:03.124] [main] [AkkaSSLConfig(akka://UpdateService)] buildHostnameVerifier: created hostname verifier: com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier@19e7a160
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:04.098] [UpdateService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://UpdateService/user/pool-master/PoolInterfaceActor-0] (Re-)starting host connection pool to 0.0.0.0:9000
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:04.315] [UpdateService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://UpdateService/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Resolving 0.0.0.0 before connecting
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:04.333] [UpdateService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://UpdateService/system/IO-DNS] Resolution request for 0.0.0.0 from Actor[akka://UpdateService/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0#-1469947037]
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:04.341] [UpdateService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://UpdateService/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Attempting connection to [/0.0.0.0:9000]
[DEBUG] [05/25/2017 01:20:14.359] [UpdateService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://UpdateService/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Connect timeout expired, could not establish connection to [0.0.0.0:9000]
```

While

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X PUT http://0.0.0.0:9000/updateJobDetails/TestJob \
-d '{"jobName":"TestJob","appId":"1234","status":"Killed","runningSince":1}'
```

works

Comment: you might want to try connecting to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Stefano Tried using `localhost` instead of 0.0.0.0   and it worked like charm, I dont know why, could you explain the reason why ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the request, which results in a `Future[HttpResponse]`.

I think you should handle the `Future` completion, either directly or by piping the result to an actor, which would then receive a message of type `HttpResponse`.

An example can be found [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.5/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#using-the-future-based-api-in-actors).

If this still gives you timeouts I would recommend to have a deeper look using Wireshark, the network traffic monitor.

Comment: The documentation clearly says:
*"Be sure to consume the response entities dataBytes:Source[ByteString,Unit] by for example connecting it to a Sink (for example response.discardEntityBytes() if you don’t care about the response entity), since otherwise Akka HTTP (and the underlying Streams infrastructure) will understand the lack of entity consumption as a back-pressure signal and stop reading from the underlying TCP connection!"*

Make sure to consume the response entity otherwise it will hang. This seems to be the problem.